# enabling crontab job for user CentOS 5.x?

Tags: linux, centos5, cron

```
cat /etc/cron.allow
root
neolix
john
```

We have added a user to run their crontab job in CentOS 5.x, still they are not able to run the job. If any thing missing from by us, Please feel free to teacher us.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't give us much to go on. Things to check.

Check cron is running

```
/sbin/service crond status
crond (pid  4186) is running...
```

If it's not then start it

```
/sbin/service crond start
```

Get the user to run `crontab -l` this will list the jobs they have defined. If they don't have any jobs defined then use `crontab -e` create them.

If they do have jobs defined then check that they should have run already - are you just not waiting long enough, look in the `/var/log/cron` file.

If the jobs are running but you are not getting your expected output then add `&>/tmp/cronjob.out` to the end of the crontab entry to capture the output of the job.

Comment: Lain thanks for your quick reply service crond status running   /sbin/service crond status
crond (pid  2887) is running...

Comment: Anything 'interesting' from the rest of the things to check ?

Comment: @Lain do you thing so this file acting funny /etc/security/access.conf

Comment: If you have made changes it's possible but by default probably not.